# handle $http response angularjs - can't get value in console.log

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

i want to use my controller for getting images link of dog with an api but I am not able to use the result.

```
var images = function(breed) {

  var promise = $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://dog.ceo/api/breed/' + breed + '/images/random'
  })
  .then(function successCallback(response) {
    return response.data.message;
  },
  function errorCallback(response) {

  });
  return promise;
}

console.log(images("kelpie"));
```

the problem is, i can't get the link in the object.

[image]

if I change response.data.message by only response.data, this is why i get

[image]

when I add console.log(response.data) before the return, this is what I get:

[image]

If I try JSON.parse(response.data), I got this:

[image]

Do you know how to do ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: can you please elaborate on the response or error you are getting?

Comment: when i look in the console, i get this: Object { $$state: Object }. When i open the object in the console, i can see the link but i am unable to reach it

Comment: can u attach a screenshot or something of the console, so we can help?

Comment: Didn't you forget to call `images ` function properly and pass a parameter to it?

Comment: add `console.log(response.data);` before `return response.data.message;` and see if it gonna output something

Comment: you misunderstand how `console.log` works.  `console.log` **is not** async;  it can't output the response of the promise, it can only output the promise itself.

Comment: So, is there a way of handling a promise ? Because I can see the link I am looking for inside of it.

Comment: it's not obvious what your *actual problem* is here.  You suggest that you aren't able to use the result, but none of your code shows that process;  all your code here is showing is you attempting to use `console.log` on a promise, which doesn't tell you anything.

Comment: i would like to display what's named "value" in the first picture

Comment: extract it *where*?? how are you trying to get the value?  You **cannot** see the value directly in a `console.log`, but you should have no problem using it in other async code.....

Comment: i woulld like to put it in the src of an image. My question is "how to get the value"

Comment: ok, so does `ng-src` not properly display the result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154076/discussion-between-gromain-and-claies).

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing in the console is the promise itself.
if you want to view the value (which in this case will be the url) then do it like this

```
console.log(images("kelpie").value);
```

If you want to see the response data then you need to add the console.log() in the `then()` callback.
Do it like this:

```
.then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response.data.message);
    return response.data.message;
  }
```

Comment: If I add ".value", this will say "undefined" in the console. I need to get the link with a return and not in a variable

Answer (score 0):

can you try one with JSON.parse(response.data) and then fetch message property from it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize promise here.
One way to do this is -

```js
angular.module('demo', [])
  .controller('myController', ['$scope', 'demoService', function($scope, demoService){
  demoService.test().then(function(response) {
      $scope.url = response;
  })
  }])
  .factory('demoService', ['$http', '$q',
  function($http, $q) {
   var demoService = {};

 demoService.test = function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then(
    function(response) {
          response = "https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/paris.jpg";
     deferred.resolve(response);
    }, function(error) {
     console.log("some error occur");
     console.log(error);
     deferred.reject(error);
    }
  )
  return deferred.promise;
 }

 return demoService;
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="myController">
  <img ng-src="{{url}}" />
</div>
```

Use promise deffer object

Refference - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

JS fiddle working code - https://jsfiddle.net/Shubhamtri/9y9ezkdt/1/